# report which method caused my NSException?

Tags: objective-c, ios, flurry

I am using Flurry Analytics which reports my app crashes, works great except I don't know which method caused the crash.

I am catching the uncaught exceptions like this:

```
{
    [FlurryAnalytics logError:@"Uncaught" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Crash! %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]] exception:exception];

}
```

If I could only see which method this would be absolutely perfect.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
NSlog(@"function that crashed %s",__FUNCTION__);
```

This is an extension to the compiler and works fine.

*UPDATE*

to get the complete call stack from the current thread use:

```
[NSThread callStackSymbols]
```

which gives you the call stack as `NSString`.

Comment: That would tell which function *caught* the exception, not which function *threw* the exception.

Comment: right. so you want to get the function one frame up the call stack?

Comment: awesome, I am grabbing this along with a username so I can really track things down - thank you!